# Is possible the deadlock happened if we don't use channel?

Tags: go

A deadlock happens when a group of goroutines are waiting for each other and none of them is able to proceed.

For example:

```
func main() {
        ch := make(chan int)
        ch <- 1
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

But is there any possibility the deadlock happened if we don't use channel?

Comment: No, an unused channel does not cause a deadlock.

Comment: It can happen with other blocking operations, for example, with mutexes.

Comment: That code blocks because it *does* use the channel, but not  correctly (unbuffered channel with no reader).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to have a deadlock, you just need one (or more) components to be waiting in such a way that noone will proceed first.

A channel is a common way to experience a deadlock in Go, but anything that is used for synchronization can trigger it as well.

Here are just some examples of simple deadlocks:

##### Mutex:

```golang
package main

import "sync"

func main() {
    var mu sync.Mutex
    mu.Lock()
    mu.Lock()
}
```

##### WaitGroup:

```golang
package main

import "sync"

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, but can you give me a brief explanation of both example of your code. Like why if we use `Lock()` twice can trigger the deadlock.. and also the second example.

Comment: Because Go mutexes are not [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex) (meaning they cannot be locked twice by the same holder). For Waitgroups because someone needs to call `wg.Done` once but there's noone to execute this.